# made a slide out animation but it is not working using CSS and Typescript

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, css-animations

So i have this ts code:

```
{/* Mobile Menu */}
        <div className="lg:hidden">
          <button className="flex items-center w-8" onClick={toggleMenu}>
            {isMobileMenuOpen ? (
              <button className="w-full h-full">
                <AiOutlineUp className="w-full h-full" />
              </button>
            ) : (
              <button className="w-full h-full">
                <AiOutlineDown className="w-full h-full" />
              </button>
            )}
          </button>
        </div>
        {/* Desktop Menu */}
        <div className="hidden lg:block">
          <ul className="flex flex-row gap-8 text-[22px]">
            {renderNavLinks(navLinks)}
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* Mobile Menu Items */}
      <div
        className={`mobileMenu lg:hidden p-10 bg-[#101010] ${
          isMobileMenuOpen ? "selected" : "dismiss"
        }`}
      >
        {isMobileMenuOpen && (
          <ul className="flex flex-col gap-4 text-[22px]">
            {renderNavLinks(navLinks)}
          </ul>
        )}
      </div>
```

and a standard css with slidein slideout keyframe animations. it works great when opening the mobile menu button, but when i close it, the animation doesnt work, it just skipped to the closed state. i have tried changing the animation using transform, making a timeout handler to no avail, any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my solution.

```
import { useState, useRef } from 'react';

const MobileMenu = ({ navLinks }) => {
  const [isMobileMenuOpen, setIsMobileMenuOpen] = useState(false);
  const mobileMenuRef = useRef(null);

  const toggleMenu = () => {
    setIsMobileMenuOpen(!isMobileMenuOpen);
  };

  const closeMenu = () => {
    const menu = mobileMenuRef.current;
    menu.addEventListener('animationend', () => {
      setIsMobileMenuOpen(false);
    }, { once: true });
    menu.classList.add('slideout');
  };

  const renderNavLinks = (navLinks) => {
    return navLinks.map((link) => (
      <li key={link.href}>
        <a href={link.href}>{link.label}</a>
      </li>
    ));
  };

  return (
    <div className="relative">
      {/* Mobile Menu */}
      <div className="lg:hidden">
        <button className="flex items-center w-8" onClick={toggleMenu}>
          {isMobileMenuOpen ? (
            <button className="w-full h-full">
              <AiOutlineUp className="w-full h-full" />
            </button>
          ) : (
            <button className="w-full h-full">
              <AiOutlineDown className="w-full h-full" />
            </button>
          )}
        </button>
      </div>
      {/* Desktop Menu */}
      <div className="hidden lg:block">
        <ul className="flex flex-row gap-8 text-[22px]">
          {renderNavLinks(navLinks)}
        </ul>
      </div>
      {/* Mobile Menu Items */}
      <div
        className={`mobileMenu lg:hidden p-10 bg-[#101010] ${
          isMobileMenuOpen ? "slidein selected" : "slideout dismiss"
        }`}
        ref={mobileMenuRef}
      >
        {isMobileMenuOpen && (
          <ul className="flex flex-col gap-4 text-[22px]">
            {renderNavLinks(navLinks)}
          </ul>
        )}
        {isMobileMenuOpen && (
          <button className="closeBtn" onClick={closeMenu}>
            <AiOutlineClose />
          </button>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot! while i needed to change some line but it worked perfectly